# Is there a Git GUI tool that always distinguishes branches in its history graph?

Tags: gui, graphs, git

I imagine this is unlikely given the graph views for most GUI clients I've seen are roughly the same, which leads me to believe they are all implemented more-or-less the same way with Git itself; however, I figured I'd ask anyway.

With all GUI clients I've tried, branches are visualized like so (SourceTree here):
[image: Current branch view]

The branch 'feature/system-agnostic-docs' appears as I'd like all branches to, as well, a branch (that in this case was merged back into 'dev'). The "problem" is that this only happens once the original branch, from which the new branch was created, gets a new commit, whether its just a standalone commit or a merge commit (i.e. from a feature branch as in this example).

As long as the base branch has no new commits, the graph displays the new branch linearly with the base branch as can be seen here with 'feature/linux_builds'.

Various discussions/explanations of git branching often give examples that show "new" branches like this:

```
1 - 2 - 3        (base_branch)
         \
          4 - 5  (feature_branch)
```

which for me at least, is much clearer at a glance than the linear display, especially when the base branch is one that will only ever receive merge commits, and as such will always show as one line until the new branch is merged.

**I know that branches are more-or-less just pointers to commits, and that the linear appearance in this example is more accurate to the actual state of the repository**

However, I still would prefer branches to be visualized as shown in the above code block for clarity (IMO), and am hoping there's a tool that can abstract such a view from the underlying `git log`.

So to summarize, is there a Git GUI client that will do something like the following in this  example?:
[image: Desired graph view]

Comment: On GitHub.com they use a network graph to visualize the different branches and forks and how they are connected. Each branch is a horizontal that goes from left to right. How about such a visualization?

Comment: @Robet While the horizontal view is nice, it still suffers from the same issue in that a new branch is still shown linearly along the same path until the base branch gets a new commit (if ever).

Comment: Maybe something like what I [recommended here](/a/77123/185)? Or rather the one from [here](/a/80913/185)?

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for the recommendations, but unfortunately they all do the same thing (to confirm I've tried Gitk/Git-GUI, Git Kraken, GitAhead, gitg, and git-cola). I'm pretty sure its because they all just take the same info from git and while they theme it different and augment it with different information, they don't change the node organization in any fundamental way.

Comment: Have a look at the ideas in https://github.com/mlange-42/git-graph

Comment: @MartinBa Not a GUI, but visual at the very least, and the example image shown on its repository looks promising! Thanks, I'll take a look.